# PHP : Convert php dictionary data set to key:valu pair

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, key-value

I have data set smiller to dictonary and I want to get key value pair for this data.
here is DATA SET:

```
$data = "{u'test_field2': u'NONE', u'test_field3': u'NONE', u'test_account': u'NONE', u'test_account_1': u'NONE'}"
```

I am doing `json_decode($data, true);` but have no luck with it

Sorry If I am unclear.f

BTW I am doing it in PHP

the result should be like this:

```
test_field2: NONE
test_field3: NONE
```

Comment: Not valid JSON...

Comment: I am afraid thats not working because that string is not valid JSON

Comment: Where are you getting that String from?

Comment: I am getting this data from database . and there is whole backend process based on django framework which manipulate and save data to database

Comment: The Django code seems to be broken. I would start by looking at that instead of trying to solve it in PHP.

Comment: I can handle django code so php is only choice for me

Comment: Then you should talk to the person that sends you that data and tell them that it's broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data is invalid json because of that `u` in it here is a solution

```
 json_decode(str_replace("'",'"',str_replace("u'","'",$data)), true);
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Thats treating the symptoms rather than killing the infection

Comment: I tested it but still giving null value

Comment: Because JSON requires double quotes,  not single quotes

Comment: Updated to reflect the single to double quotes

Comment: And if any value would happen to contain a `'` or end with a `u`, this would break the string further.

Comment: Probably, I am only providing an answer to the data listed above, not a complete solution for him to use in 100% cases.  The fact that this data contains an `u` in it is VERY SUSPICIOUS, and I suspect any kind of `str_replace` will be broken in the future

Comment: _"I am only providing an answer to the data listed above"_ - Sure, but in that case, why not just discard the string and have `$value = 'NONE';` as answer?

Comment: @Forbs you are genius. :*

Answer (score 0):

You've to try like this because on your existing code couple of issue exists.

1. Replace Unnecessary character `u'` with `'`
2. Replace single quotes(`'`) on json string. For json double quotes(`"`) is permitted.

So just search these two characters and replace with `''` and `"` respectively.

```
<?php
$data = "{u'test_field2': u'NONE', u'test_field3': u'NONE', u'test_account': u'NONE', u'test_account_1': u'NONE'}";
$search = ["u'","'"];
$replace = ["'",'"'];
$without_u = str_replace($search,$replace,$data);
$array  = json_decode($without_u, true);
print '<pre>';
print_r($array);
print '</pre>';
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/1032316

Comment: That may make the JSON valid, but stripping all u's is a bad idea

Comment: @Devon yes you are ri8, it was my bad. see the edit now :)

Comment: And what would happen if any of the values ended with `u`?